# how to pause the execution of a function on a boolean variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, thread-sleep

I'm essentially envisioning a "traffic light" that has green and red lights. When the light is green we are allowed to `doWork()`. When the light is red I need to wait until `doMaintenance()` is complete before allowing `doWork()` to execute. I have done the following and it seems to behave correctly, but I'm wondering if this is a naive solution:

```
private volatile boolean lightIsGreen = true;

public void doSomeWorkIfLightIsGreen() {
    while(!lightIsGreen) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1); // I'm not sure what value to put here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Log exception
        }
    }

    doWork();
}
```

And then there is a separate function in the same class that runs every so often:

```
private void doMaintenance() {
  lightIsGreen = false;
  doMaintenance();
  lightIsGreen = true;
}
```

In my actual code, `doMaintenance()` is given several opportunities to successfully complete. If it cannot complete, then the entire application shuts down gracefully.

Is there a better / more elegant way of accomplishing this "traffic light" functionality?

Edit: I should mention that the `doSomeWorkIfLightIsGreen()` can be called from several threads and I do not want to cause those threads to have to execute one at a time. I think this means I cannot use Semaphores or ReentrantLock or any solution that required locking. Ultimately, what i'm trying to accomplish is to allow any thread calling `doSomeWorkIfLightIsGreen()` to successfully execute when the "light" is green but not allow any thread at all to execute when the "light" is red.

Comment: It is naive. There are better ways to do this eg. use `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll` or `ReentrantLock`, or `Semaphores`. Anything that is created to introduce thread synchronization would do.

Comment: A Semaphore might be the most appropriate one given how you described it. You basically answered yourself.

Comment: @LppEdd If I use a Semaphore, I would just be replacing the volatile boolean with the Semaphore right? I would still need to do a `Thread.sleep()` inside of my waiting loop?

Comment: @rage if you use a Semaphore, the boolean lightIsGreen variable can be ditched. It is no more needed. Thread.sleep too.

Comment: @rage Jenkov has a great explanation http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/semaphore.html

Comment: Semaphores allowes to WAIT for permits. No sleeps there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the expected behavior if one thread calls `doMaintainance()` while another thread already is executing inside `doWork()`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow - the expectation is that `doWork()` fails but retries itself a configurable amount of times with some delays in order to give time for `doMaintenance()` to finish

Comment: OK, but how will it know to "fail" if it already has started before the other thread enters `doMaintenance()`? Is it possible that what you really want is a shared _[mutex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)_ that both functions lock while they are active? (i.e., force `doWork()` to wait if the other thread already is in `doMaintenance()`, and likewise force `doMaintenance()` to wait if the first thread already has started to `doWork()`.)

Comment: `doWork()` will not know to fail - it just has the possibility of failing if `doMaintenance()` is currently executing.

I was reading more about `Semaphores` and `ReentrantLock` but I think using either of those would effectively single thread the `doWorkIfLightIsGreen()` which is not what I want.

I want to let any threads that call `doWorkIfLightIsGreen()` to go ahead and call `doWork()` if the "light" is green. I don't want to force each thread to go one at a time.

Comment: That sounds like maybe you want a _[reader/writer lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)_.